# Possible missing firmware

Tags: drivers, 16.04, kernel, firmware

Issue:

```
 sudo update-initramfs -u
[sudo] password for abhishek: 
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1.bin for module i915_bpo
```

I have already installed both https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/skylake-guc-6.1 and https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/skylake-dmc-1.26, as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811453/w-possible-missing-firmware-for-module-i915-bpo-when-updating-initramfs).

Machine Info:

```
inxi -Fxz
System:    Host: neon Kernel: 4.4.0-53-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.8.4 (Qt 5.7.0) Distro: neon 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: HP (portable) product: HP Pavilion Notebook v: Type1ProductConfigId
           Mobo: HP model: 80A4 v: 91.1D Bios: Insyde v: F.79 date: 04/14/2016
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-6500U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 4096 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 10367
           clock speeds: max: 3100 MHz 1: 531 MHz 2: 502 MHz 3: 1521 MHz 4: 545 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Sky Lake Integrated Graphics bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940M] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1920x1080@60.01hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.4.0-53-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: rtl8723be port: 4000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 3000 bus-ID: 04:00.0
           IF: eno1 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (80.8% used) ID-1: /dev/sda model: Samsung_SSD_850 size: 500.1GB temp: 0C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 443G used: 362G (87%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 17.01GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda3
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 45.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 250 Uptime: 58 min Memory: 3020.4/15886.3MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (fish) inxi: 2.2.35
```

dmesg:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/23635753/

Comment: You can safely ignore these i915 driver warning messages. They've been coming out for months on advanced kernels and 4.4.0-53 is simply catching up.

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/811453/w-possible-missing-firmware-for-module-i915-bpo-when-updating-initramfs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updated kernel to 4.8 now missing firmware warnings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832524/updated-kernel-to-4-8-now-missing-firmware-warnings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the warning is harmless. The *possible* missing firmware is for brand-new Kaby Lake CPU (`kbl` in the file name), and you have a previous-gen Skylake CPU (which makes use of firmware with `skl` in the file name).

I have an even older CPU, and I get two such warnings (one for `kbl` firmware, the other for `skl` firmware), with no ill-effects that I can detect.

Do you have a particular problem with your CPU/GPU, or are you simply worried about the warning?

Comment: The dmesg shows a segfault in the end.

Comment: The segault is completely unrelated (the `baloo` file content indexer has crashed for some reason).