# Missing firmware warning during update

Tags: package-management, updates

I get this line repeatedly:

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
```

This is the whole process (German): https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25227658/

What is this about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/811453/423684

Comment: I've search the pastbin log, and the word "error" didn't match anything, so it is safe to assume it is a warning.

Comment: I looked at the other post but it didn't seem related because it was about Nvidia and Kaby Lake. I don't have this hardware in my system. Also I don't get the solution posted. Should I just leave it?