# Missing firmware on the new LTS kernel

Tags: 16.04, drivers, kernel

I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and my cpu is intel i5-7300hq. After updating today I got kernel `4.13.0-26-generic` from `4.10.0-42-generic`. During the update process I got the following warnings:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-26-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_ver02_00_1810.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_huc_ver01_07_1398.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_huc_ver01_07_1398.bin for module i915
```

How do I fix those missing firmware? I think the solution is to get the new `linux-firmware` package from [here](https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/) but I am not sure which one is appropriate for kernel 4.13. Or is there another way to fix this?

**Edit** Regarding the [possible duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811453/w-possible-missing-firmware-for-module-i915-bpo-when-updating-initramfs) suggested. The answers there suggest downloading some binaries straight from intel. Isn't that though more risky compared to getting the proper `linux-firmware` package that integrates them more properly with the operating system to make sure weird bugs don't arise?

Here is the information of the current linux-firmware package:

```
$ apt policy linux-firmware
linux-firmware:
  Installed: 1.161.1
  Candidate: 1.161.1
```

The newer versions available from [Ubuntu](https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/) are 1.164, 1.169, 1.170. But I don't know which one corresponds to the 4.13 kernel.

Comment: 4.13 is not LTS (see [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2FSupport.A16.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support), it will be supported until middle of 2018). Install 4.4 and you will not have problems.

Comment: @N0rbert Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with HWE uses 4.13 kernel so this is an LTS issue.

Comment: @Terrance I run the reinstall command you wrote. Everything worked fine, but how can I tell if the missing firmwares are a problem or not? Additionally I only have one 4.13 kernel installed (the previous is 4.10) and re-installing it (the actual kernel I mean) may cause problems - since it ll be running at the same time.

Comment: @Karsus I actually deleted that comment, but it looks like the linked answers can fix that.  I actually ran the second answer listed on my work system just now and seems to be working well.  =)

Comment: Unless the missing firmware is one for the card you are using, it doesn't matter. The warning just states that some kernel modules do not have the firmware associated with them.

Comment: `\`\`\`` is not the proper way to format multiline terminal output. Please select terminal output with your mouse and press the `{}` button in the editor to format it (which adds four spaces to the beginning of each line, marking a multiline code block).