# Missing firmware warnings during update

Tags: nvidia, kernel, firmware

On my Dell Latitude 5491 with Ubuntu 18.04.2. LTS, (kernel 4.19), there seems to be a problem with the graphic card hardware.

Previously, I used to choose the option "install third party modules" during Ubuntu installation with the standard kernel, and there were so many kernel freezes that the usage was almost impossible.

In the current installation without that third party modules everything works very smooth but then after moving to the latest upstream kernel I get these warnings on `apt-get upgrade`.

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.19.20-041920-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/unload_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
```

How to assess and fix this? As far as I can see, [nouveau](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/) is an up to date open source driver, but I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Note that this is merely a warning. It is probable that a kernel update added support for your processor, but it needs a module for it. However, that module has not yet been added to the firmware package. Such was the case in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811453/w-possible-missing-firmware-for-module-i915-bpo-when-updating-initramfs), which also provides some links and a workaround, albeit for a different processor and video card.