# sudo apt update Erros — W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau

Tags: nvidia

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/unload_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau
```

Comment: See this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117305/missing-firmware-warnings-during-update 
It's just warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Reason:Missing firmware warnings during update - Nvidia, nouveau

```
sudo find / -name "scrubber.bin"
sudo find / -name "sig.bin"
sudo find / -name "sw_method_init.bin"
sudo find / -name "ucode_unload.bin"
```

Step 1: Query the computer if these firmware exists, but the firmware file directory error, should be gv100 directory, is now in the gp100 gp107 directory
`/lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100  /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107`

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100
cd /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp100
sudo cp -r  acr/ gr/ ../gv100/
cd ../gp107
sudo cp -r  sec2/ nvdec/ ../gv100/
```

again run `sudo apt update`. No more errors occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [yfluK](https://askubuntu.com/users/1107512/yfluk) and [herex](https://askubuntu.com/users/977683/herex) I have the same issue whit Debian 10 buster, and after update this directories with the `ucode_unload.bin` as mention above warning message gone for me too.