# help! W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, uefi

How can I solve this warning?

```
addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up grub-common (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.21) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Setting up grub2-common (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.21) ...
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-bin (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.21) ...
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.21) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-45-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.66.21+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.21) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Setting up busybox-initramfs (1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up busybox-static (1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up libpolkit-gobject-1-0:amd64 (0.105-14.1ubuntu0.5) ...
Setting up libpolkit-agent-1-0:amd64 (0.105-14.1ubuntu0.5) ...
Setting up libpolkit-backend-1-0:amd64 (0.105-14.1ubuntu0.5) ...
Setting up libpq5:amd64 (9.5.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.4.0-145.171) ...
Setting up linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04 (4.15.0.47.68) ...
Setting up policykit-1 (0.105-14.1ubuntu0.5) ...
Removed symlink /run/systemd/system/polkitd.service.
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.14) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915
Processing triggers for shim-signed (1.33.1~16.04.4+15+1533136590.3beb971-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updated kernel to 4.8 now missing firmware warnings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832524/updated-kernel-to-4-8-now-missing-firmware-warnings)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix don't know if it makes any difference, but OP is running 4.15.0-46.

Comment: @heynnema These warnings first started with Kernel 4.8 release. At the time 4.8 was off-topic and the duplicate candidate was closed. The warnings continued with subsequent kernels after 4.8 and the duplicate candidate was re-opened. We will likely see these warnings for many years at this rate. With drivers missing there are certain Intel features you can't use.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix as per my answer, doesn't reinstalling linux-firmware replace the missing files? Looks like it does to me. No?

Comment: @heynnema I tried your answer early this morning and it doesn't work for kernel 5.0 but it is using newer Intel Drivers than the kernel 4.14 I booted with so it's not a complete test. I posted preliminary results in an answer below before this question gets closed...

Answer (score 26):

Just get the file from the kernel git:

`git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git`

`sudo cp ./linux-firmware/i915/icl_dmc_ver1_07.bin /lib/firmware/i915/icl_dmc_ver1_07.bin`

Comment: In my case I needed a different file `sudo cp ./linux-firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_04.bin /lib/firmware/i915/` but the basic idea was correct. Thank you!

Comment: Just to save your data use `--depth=1` for a shallow clone.

`git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git --depth=1`

Answer (score 3):

This answer appears to best solution for missing Intel Graphics Driver warnings:

- [Updated kernel to 4.8 now missing firmware warnings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832524/updated-kernel-to-4-8-now-missing-firmware-warnings)

---

As requested in comments it appears warnings do not go away with `linux-firmware` reinstall:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 49.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 1.157.21 [49.8 MB]
Fetched 49.8 MB in 8s (5,542 kB/s)                                                         
(Reading database ... 495159 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware_1.157.21_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.157.21) over (1.157.21) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (1.157.21) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-47-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.14.110-0414110-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.14.98-041498-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.14.89-041489-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.14.78-041478-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.14.70-041470-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-145-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.60-031660-generic
```

Comment: You installed an older `linux-firmware 1.157.21`. Newer versions do contain the  required files, except for 1.

Comment: On 18.10 w/4.18 kernel, `linux-firmware 1.175.1` has all of the files that you show as possibly missing, except for icl_dmc_ver1_07.bin. With running kernel 5.0.1, the linux-firmware file you used was too old. So the Intel web site might be required in your case example.

Comment: **So it looks like my answer is correct**... unless you're running with a *rogue* kernel :-)

Comment: With kernel 5.0.1 you may need to install this linux-firmware... https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/linux-firmware

Comment: @heynnema I'm not using 5.0.1 because it's missing DKMS support for various drivers I need. Although installed I've never booted it. The other kernels already had `.bin` drivers for Skylake, Broxton, Kabylake, etc. installed so there would be no warning messages. What I can do is rename the `.bin` drivers and then run `linux-firmware` reinstall to see if it installs them for kernel 4.14.110 which I'm running now. If it doesn't then it's back to the **BLOB** (**B**inary **L**arge **OB**ject) as the only way to install. As far as it being an older version, it was a fresh 16.04 install this year.

Comment: I saw all of your `update-initramfs` output, and 5.0.1 was the only one that generated the errors. That's why I gave you the `Disco` link for the latest firmware. Why aren't you running with 18.04/18.10? Are you not going to do 19.04 later this month? What dkms drivers don't work with 5.0.1?

Comment: I did a test deleting .bin in /lib/firmware/i915 and linux-firmware does the trick alright. I updated my old answer to save people time. I've tried 18.04 a few times but enjoy 16.04 Unity much better. I might wait for 20.04. I definitely don't do 15.04, 16.10, 17.04, 18.10, 19.04, etc. I spend most my time developing software and don't want to be distracted with new interfaces, gsettings or whatever.

Comment: @heynnema I'm upvoting your answer. I will be deleting this answer soon since it was all about experimenting and fact finding with a whole bunch of comments thrown in which the mods hate (and rightfully so as they distract from the website).

Comment: Looks like you need to update this answer also. You didn't say what dkms driver problems you had with 5.0.1. Lastly... 16.04 vs 18.04/10... Unity vs GNOME... not really that much GUI difference. The big difference is with netplan... a real PITA.

Comment: @heynnema I don't remember which DKMS drivers weren't working for sure. I think it was nVidia 384.10 and nvhda (which is custom sound over HDMI on Optimus laptops with GTX 970M, 1060, etc where manufacturers power off the sound channel on boot). I think there is a DKMS for Virtual Box but I haven't used that since last year. Part of a project to record grub boot screen where I changed second to 1/10th of second for smooth circle progress countdown on Grub Graphics boot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51341871/finding-countdown-timer-in-grub-2-02-source-code/52138789#52138789.

Comment: @heynnema With 1 second interval the grub countdown graphics make "big block" circles and you don't get smooth transition unless you modify grub to be 1/10th of a second. I don't get out much :P

Comment: @heynnema I upvoted too soon. I deleted the `kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin` that OP was missing and `linux-firmware` doesn't add it back in. As Doug Smithies said in his post (https://askubuntu.com/a/811487/307523) Ubuntu tends to lag behind on drivers. So OP will have to download Intel BLOB as in my answer.

Comment: You're probably still loading an old `linux-firmware` file. The 18.10 `linux-firmware` contains that .bin, as (probably) the **disco** version of `linux-firmware` link that I gave you. We've got to get you out of the 16.04 world... and into the 21st century my friend.

Comment: @heynnema I think 2016 was in the 21st century :p. As far as whether or not OP needs to upgrade his `linux-firmware` to a different repository I can't say. But I downloaded the BLOB I deleted and everything is OK on my system now. I'm not keen on putting DISCO on top of XENIAL...

Comment: I think that OP is running a newer kernel than you, so that version `linux-firmware` probably contains that .bin. Of course, you could download that `linux-firmware` and confirm that... :-)

Comment: @heynnema I have no idea. Hopefully OP signs on soon and updates us. I've revised the answer with only the error OP and I both got.

Answer (score 2):

In `terminal`...

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware` # reinstall firmware

and

`sudo pico /etc/default/grub` # edit grub defaults

change:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

to:

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

Save file. Exit editor. (control-o, return, control-x)

`sudo update-grub` # update GRUB

Comment: It would help newbies to include "Save file using `Ctrl`+`O`" and "Exit editor using `Ctrl`+`X`" :) I'm probably one of the few here that have used DEC/Vax Clusters :P

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Edit done. Thanks! DEC was the best company I ever worked for. 16 years. Miss it.

Comment: I was more into big blue, AS/400, System/36, S/390, etc. Haha and IBM PC/AT too of course :P