# i915 missing firmware error message during kernel 6.2.0-26 installation on Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, 22.04

The **22.04** hardware enablement package was updated a few minutes ago installing kernel **6.2.0-26** on the system. The problem is that during the image generation this message appeared:

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg2_huc_gsc.bin for module i915
```

How is this fixed please?

Comment: There is a question and answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811453/w-possible-missing-firmware-for-module-i915-bpo-when-updating-initramfs) that still applies. I now use [the git method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131885/help-w-possible-missing-firmware-lib-firmware-i915-kbl-guc-ver9-14-bin-for-mo/1132350#1132350), linked to in my answer as "Edit 3:"

Comment: @DougSmythies, copying the .bin file and regenerating the new kernel corrected the issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'll suggest one of you @DougSmythies or Stormlord write an answer to this.. The HWE stack upgrading (5.19 to 6.2 for *jammy*) has loads of users looking for 'answers' to their newly discovered issues (*kernels have been available for testing for 3+ weeks now; 7 weeks if willing to use -proposed edge too*) but few test & report findings (*via QA & bug reports*) & those that do often have different hardware thus different experiences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am posting this answer, although I think it may not be necessary since a few minutes ago on August 5, there was a `linux-firmware` update that may have fixed the issue.

In case the issue still exists after this update, the way to fix it is by downloading the required `.bin` file from [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/i915) and copying it as root to the `/lib/firmware/i915` folder. Right after that, the **6.2.0-26** image needs to be regenerated by executing:

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

This will update the latest kernel image only, which in this case is the **6.2.0-26** image. There should be no errors or warnings after this but the system should be rebooted for the updated kernel to be loaded.

Comment: I just tried this, having encountered the same problem; and while the error messages about the missing are gone, I still get: `E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/dmsetup failed with return 1.` - with no other apparent error. Do you have any idea why that might happen?

Answer (score 0):

From [Debian bug #1040012](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1040012) this looks like it was due to a packaging oversight in `firmware-misc-nonfree` and has been resolved - that will filter down to ubuntu soon hopefully.

What the module actually is is a bit mysterious the [commit adding it to the kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/commit/i915/dg2_huc_gsc.bin?id=8f86b5ab3e051170ea240fc409d457e16e24bc21) just says "i915: Add HuC 7.10.3 for DG2". But, [from discussion on intel-gfx](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/intel-gfx/2022-September/306043.html) this is basically all around a transition in the intel graphics driver firmware handling.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem in unstable(SID): my `firmware-misc-nonfree/unstable` package was stuck in version `20221214-1`.  It couldn't download the recent `20230515-3`  because my `/etc/apt/sources.list` wasn't properly updated to include the newly added repo for firmware packages,  as suggested by apt update command:

```bash
$ sudo apt update
...
N: Repository 'Debian bookworm' changed its 'non-free component' value from 'non-free' to 'non-free non-free-firmware'
N: More information about this can be found online in the Release notes at: https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.html#non-free-split
```

All missing firmware blobs were found in the kernel's initramfs after adding the `non-free-firmware` repo at the end of the deb-lines, and executing `sudo apt update` and `sudo at upgrade`, as [instructed](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.html#non-free-split):

```bash
$ head /etc/apt/sources.list
deb [arch=amd64] https://deb.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://deb.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
```