# Is kernel 6.2.0-26 ready to be used on 22.04 systems?

Tags: kernel, updates, 22.04

After the HWE kernel update on August 3, 2023, several things started appearing on my **Xubuntu 22.04** system's `journald.log` that weren't appearing either with kernel **5.15** or **5.19**.

The first one was the issue I posted yesterday [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1480917/i915-missing-firmware-error-message-during-kernel-6-2-0-26-installation-on-xubun) and luckily was solved by downloading the `.bin` file manually and regenerating the kernel image. Why should that be necessary though?

The second issue is the fact that I keep getting this entry in the log at random intervals:

```
pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:01:00.0
```

The third issue is that the following bunch of entries concerning `alsa` keep appearing on every system startup:

```
controlC0: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore 0' failed with exit code 99
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #47 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #48 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #49 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #50 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #51 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #52 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #53 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #54 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #55 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #56 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #57 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #58 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #59 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #60 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #61 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #62 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #63 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #64 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #65 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #66 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #67 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #68 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #69 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #70 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #71 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #72 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #73 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #74 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #75 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #76 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #77 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #78 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #79 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #80 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #81 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #82 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #83 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #84 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #85 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #86 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #87 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #88 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #89 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #90 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #91 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #92 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #93 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #94 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #99 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #100 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #101 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #102 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #103 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #104 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #105 (No such file or directory)
Aug  4 20:03:35 IdCentre alsactl[1003]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: set_control:1339: failed to obtain info for control #106 (No such file or directory)
```

Despite these issues, the system seems to be working OK but I'm not sure about what I should do. What exactly is going on with kernel **6.2.0-26**? Should I keep using it or should I go back to the **GA** kernel where none of the issues above were happening?

Thank you!

Comment: These look like typical bugs that are usually discovered by testing volunteers. Seems like too few folks tested on their hardware before release. More volunteers testing and reporting  = Fewer bugs after release.

Comment: Depending on your hardware/system, on most of my LTS releases I have both GA & HWE stacks installed; so I can select which I'll use at grub at boot (*note: some closed-source kernel modules (nvidia etc) prevent this from occurring, but all open source allow for it, including most closed-source kernel modules!*).  My current *jammy* box has both stacks installed