# W: possible missing firmware for module i915

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, i915

W: possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg2_huc_gsc.bin module i915

Kubuntu 22.04
2023
I can't find ANYTHING about this. the CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU  M 580  @ 2.67GHz

Somebody please help me out here. I've been looking for hours.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147709/discussion-on-question-by-daedae311-w-possible-missing-firmware-for-module-i915); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: This question is duplicated. The solution is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1480917/i915-missing-firmware-error-message-during-kernel-6-2-0-26-installation-on-xubun).